# replacing multiple letter in a string javascript

Tags: javascript, replace, charat

Hi I am looking to compare two strings and have all the lowercase letters in string B -which are uppercase letters in string A- to uppercase, the problem with my code is it only changes the last letter like this

```js
var i;
var x;

function switchItUp(before, after) {
  for (i = 0; i < before.length; i++) {
    if (before.charAt(i) == before.charAt(i).toUpperCase()) {
      x = after.replace(after.charAt(i), after.charAt(i).toUpperCase());

    }
  }

  console.log(x);
}




switchItUp("HiYouThere", "biyouthere");
```

this will result in "biyouThere" any way to change it to "HiYouThere" ?

Comment: Expected output should be HiYouThere or BiYouThere?

Comment: I expected BiYouThere

Comment: Ok. then assign value of 'after' to x before starting the loop and use x only inside the loop instead of 'after'.

Comment: it works but it shows the string in the console multiple times (for each iteration)

Comment: Print outside the loop only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code correctly to work. You needed to apply the operation to the same variable, x, not after, in every loop.

```
function switchItUp(before, after) {
  var x = after;
  for (i = 0; i < before.length; i++) {
    if (before.charAt(i) == before.charAt(i).toUpperCase()) {
      x = x.replace(after.charAt(i), after.charAt(i).toUpperCase());

    }
  }

  console.log(x);
}
```

Comment: it works but it shows the string in the console multiple times (for each iteration)

Comment: It only shows one iteration for me: https://jsbin.com/dotejenoho/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Why introduce another variable called `x`? Also, this will turn all characters in the second string into uppercase if the corresponding character in the first string is a digit.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign each changes. It's working now

```
var i;
var x;

function switchItUp(before, after) {
  for (i = 0; i < before.length; i++) {
    if (before.charAt(i) == before.charAt(i).toUpperCase()) {
      x = after.replace(after.charAt(i), after.charAt(i).toUpperCase());
      after = x; 
      //console.log("inside"+x);
    }
  }

  console.log(x);
}

switchItUp("HiYouThere", "biyouthere");
```

Comment: it works but it shows the string in the console multiple times (for each iteration)

Comment: no problem its just a console.log inside iteration loop :)

Comment: It seems very clumsy to modify `x` based on `after` and then set `after` right back to `x`. How is this different/better than just saying `after = after.replace...`?

Comment: ya..its seems..for better point of their bug..i did it...thanks for suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

This is code:

```js
function switchItUp(before, after) {
  for (var i = 0; i < before.length; i++) {
    if (before.charAt(i) == before.charAt(i).toUpperCase()) {
      after = after.replace(after.charAt(i), after.charAt(i).toUpperCase());
    }
  }
  return after;
}

var after = switchItUp("HiYouThere", "biyouthere");

document.body.innerHTML+='<p style="color: black;">'+ after + '<p/>';
```